# HtmlAgilityPack / XPath find all occurences after specific tag / before next tag

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

Agility newbie here. Given input text:

```
<html>
  ... Lots of html here...
  <label class="list_item_title">Yes</label><br /><br />
    <div class="list_item">
        <div style="width:425px;" class="left"><a href="/xyz">HIT1</a>  (2012)</div>
        <div style="width:190px;" class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="list_item">
        <div style="width:425px;" class="left"><a href="/abc">HIT2</a>  (2012)</div>
        <div style="width:190px;" class="right"></div>
    </div>
  <label class="list_item_title">No</label><br /><br />
  <div class="list_item">
        <div style="width:425px;" class="left"><a href="/xyz">IGNORE</a>  (2012)</div>
        <div style="width:190px;" class="right"></div>
  </div>
  ... Lots of html here...
</html>
```

I want to get HIT1 & HIT2.

Basically the algorithm is to find the innerText of all A after the label node (class="list_item_title") where innerText="Yes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath expression works for your example:

```
//a[preceding::label[1][text()="Yes"]]/text()
```

It looks for all `a` whose first preceding `label` contains `Yes` and returns their text().

Comment: Perfect. the [1] after label was what I was missing